# Compile Error: Duplicate Declaration

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code here:

```
Dim c As Long, rG As Range, vR As Variant
c = wsC.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet
Set wsA = Sheets("Active")
Set wsC = Sheets("Closed")
wsA.Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
Set rG = Range("X" & i)
vR = rG.Value
If InStr(vR, "/") > 0 Then
    rG.EntireRow.Copy wsC.Cells(c, 1)
    rG.EntireRow.Delete
    c = c + 1
End If
Next I
```

However when I run the code it highlights:

```
wsC As Worksheet
```

in yellow with a pop up saying:

> Microsoft Visual Basic
>
> Compile error:
>
> Duplicate Declaration in current scope

However if I put this code:

```
Dim c As Long, rG As Range, vR As Variant
c = 1000
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet
Set wsA = Sheets("Active")
Set wsC = Sheets("Closed")
wsA.Activate
For i = ActiveSheet.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
Set rG = Range("X" & i)
vR = rG.Value
If InStr(vR, "/") > 0 Then
    rG.EntireRow.Copy wsC.Cells(c, 1)
    rG.EntireRow.Delete
    c = c + 1
End If
Next I
```

The code runs successfully, However the only problem having this code is that if I have more than 1000 cell entries then it will start replacing at cell A1000. What I am trying to accomplish is have it paste in column A but at the first free cell. Anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Many thanks ahead of time.

Comment: You are setting c equal to a value from wsC before you set wsC. (See line 2 and 5). (Edit: the original comment of mine sounded jerkish)

Comment: So I figured such, so I took c = wsC...... and placed it after the Dim wsA wsC line and the code bugged out. Such as:

    Dim c As Long, rG As Range, vR As Variant
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet
    c = wsC.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set wsA = Sheets("Active")
    Set wsC = Sheets("Closed")

What am I missing here I need to figure this out before I go to work monday morning I have to present this to my President of my company.

Comment: to avoid such problems, on the top of your module add: Option Explicit

Comment: So is the question now answered? @JoeyGrant's comment addressed the apparent issue.

Comment: yes this is fixed thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With some help from @RADO and @Joey Grant I'm glad I got this fixed! Thank you so much guys! this is what I ended up with. Let me know anyone has any better ideas.

```
Dim c As Long, rG As Range, vR As Variant
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsC As Worksheet

Set wsA = Sheets("Active")
Set wsC = Sheets("Closed")

c = wsC.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
wsA.Activate

For i = ActiveSheet.Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    Set rG = Range("X" & i)
    vR = rG.Value
    If InStr(vR, "/") > 0 Then
        rG.EntireRow.Copy wsC.Cells(c, 1)
        rG.EntireRow.Delete
        c = c + 1
    End If
Next i
```

Thank you so much Stackoverflow community you guys rock!

Comment: Note that you can mark your own answer as solution after a while.